# TCL\Expect:: spawn ssh shows "The system cannot find the file specified" Error

Tags: windows, ssh, tcl, expect

I am facing a Problem, while doing spawn ssh in windows.

```
% spawn ssh root@4.2.2.2
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have tried adding the plink.exe file on Path as below.

```
 "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe"
```

But no luck. Still facing the same problem, could anyone please help me resolving this.

Comment: Which one are you going to use? Putty's plink.exe or Win10 native ssh command? Or else?

Comment: Have you tried `spawn plink root@4.2.2.2` instead?

Comment: Hi Donal Fellows, I have tried the same, but no luck. Getting the same error. Now I am trying to do it in different Windows machine, here I am getting different error. "The request is not supported"

Comment: Now it is resolved, after adding path of expect package to Env variables, Thanks